# Dynamic Search using Suitetalk

Tags: c#, search, netsuite

I am trying to create a C# application (Using suitetalk) that would allow us to search through Netsuite records. The record type will be specified dynamically. Please can you help?

I have checked the webservices and identified that SearchRecord class has many sub classes of type AccountSearch, ItemSearch, etc.

However, I wanted to do these searches dynamically.

```
            AccountSearch acc = new AccountSearch();

            SearchResult searchresult = new SearchResult();

            searchresult = _service.search(acc);
```

The above code gives me the list of accounts. But, the AccountSearch is hardcoded here.

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code below works.

```
SearchRecord search;
SearchRecord searchCriteria;
SearchRecordBasic searchBasicCriteria;

if(recordType.equals(RecordType.account)){
    search = new AccountSearchAdvanced();
    searchCriteria = new AccountSearch();
    searchBasicCriteria = new AccountSearchBasic();

    //set criteria on searchBasicCriteria 

    ((AccountSearch) searchCriteria).setBasic((AccountSearchBasic) searchBasicCriteria);
    ((AccountSearchAdvanced) search).setCriteria((AccountSearch) searchCriteria);
}else if(recordType.equals(RecordType.customer)){
    search = new CustomerSearchAdvanced();
    searchCriteria = new CustomerSearch();
    searchBasicCriteria = new CustomerSearchBasic();

    //set criteria on searchBasicCriteria 

    ((CustomerSearch) searchCriteria).setBasic((CustomerSearchBasic) searchBasicCriteria);
    ((CustomerSearchAdvanced) search).setCriteria((CustomerSearch) searchCriteria);
}else{
    search = null;
}

if(search != null) _service.search(search);
```

But I think a better solution would be to create specific methods for each type of search. That way the code is more readable, plus you avoid all that casting. Then you would have to handle the returned RecordList for each specific record type.

Comment: I understand that casting has a cost and this code is not the most beautiful thing. Is not even in C#.

But I still would think this is helpful somehow. Would be great to know why that's not the case.